# Symfony 4 JWT authentication - Pre login event listener

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Is it possible to trigger pre-login event listener to check if user status is enabled with JWT authentication ?

I want something like that in my listener:

```
if (!$user->getStatus()) {
   return new JsonResponse(['message': 'Your account is not activated'],403)
}
```

The default config of jwt in my security.yaml is:

```
firewalls:        
       login:
            pattern: ^/api/1.0/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/1.0/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
```

**SOLVED**
I have finally created a custom provider which is more simple to implement.

My custom UserProvider:

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->loadUserByUsername($username);
        if (null === $user) {
            throw new \Exception('User account is not confirmed. Please check your email or reset your password');
        }

        return $user;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

My UserRepository:

```
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername(string $email) {
        try {
            return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->andWhere('u.email = :email')
                ->setParameter('email', $email)
                ->andWhere('u.enabled = :status')
                ->setParameter('status', true)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult();
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Error server. Please contact an administrator');
        }
    }
}
```

My security.yaml:

```
    providers:
        api_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        jwt_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider

    ...
    ...

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/1.0/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: jwt_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/1.0/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: jwt_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Comment: Extend JWTAuthenticator. https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-extending-jwt-authenticator.md and override getUser() method where you can check $user->getStatus() before creating token or loging in.

Comment: or you can create your own UserProvider check, https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/8-jwt-user-provider.md   and https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider

Comment: It's worked with custom UserProvider. I have updated my main post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create event listener for `Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\JWTCreatedEvent` event and this listener will check your user and throw custom exception, but in this moment jwt token will be created.

event name: `lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created`